# kube-controller-manager unable to communicate with etcd

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

**1. What `kops` version are you running? The command `kops version`, will display
 this information.**
`Version 1.12.2`

**2. What Kubernetes version are you running? `kubectl version` will print the
 version if a cluster is running or provide the Kubernetes version specified as
 a `kops` flag.**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.1", GitCommit:"4485c6f18cee9a5d3c3b4e523bd27972b1b53892", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-18T14:25:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.8", GitCommit:"a89f8c11a5f4f132503edbc4918c98518fd504e3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-23T04:41:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**3. What cloud provider are you using?**
`aws`
**4. What commands did you run?  What is the simplest way to reproduce this issue?**
`kops update cluster` 
`kops rolling-update`
**5. What happened after the commands executed?**
kube-controller-manager reports the following error while

```
Unable to sync caches for garbage collector controller
Failed to list <nil>: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"
```

**6. What did you expect to happen?**
Upgrade kubernetes

**7. Please provide your cluster manifest. Execute
  `kops get --name my.example.com -o yaml` to display your cluster manifest.
  You may want to remove your cluster name and other sensitive information.**

```
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-05-14T16:15:12Z
  name: k8s.runningenv.cloud
spec:
  api:
    dns: {}
    loadBalancer:
      sslCertificate: arn:aws:acm:ca-central-1:111111111111:certificate/ccxcccss112-ddw-ddwd-ddsds-ddsds3232
      type: Public
  authentication:
    aws: {}
  authorization:
    rbac: {}
  channel: stable
  cloudProvider: aws
  configBase: s3://dummy-data-store/k8s.runningenv.cloud
  etcdClusters:
  - etcdMembers:
    - instanceGroup: master-ca-central-1a
      name: a
    name: main
  - etcdMembers:
    - instanceGroup: master-ca-central-1a
      name: a
    name: events
  iam:
    allowContainerRegistry: true
    legacy: false
  kubelet:
    anonymousAuth: false
  kubernetesApiAccess:
  - 1.1.1.1/32
  - 2.2.2.2/32 
  kubernetesVersion: 1.12.8
  masterInternalName: api.internal.k8s.runningenv.cloud
  masterPublicName: api.k8s.runningenv.cloud
  networkCIDR: 172.20.0.0/16
  networking:
    amazonvpc: {}
  nonMasqueradeCIDR: 172.20.0.0/16
  sshAccess:
  - 1.1.1.1/32
  - 2.2.2.2/32
  subnets:
  - cidr: 172.20.32.0/19
    name: ca-central-1a
    type: Public
    zone: ca-central-1a
  - cidr: 172.20.64.0/19
    name: ca-central-1b
    type: Public
    zone: ca-central-1b
  topology:
    dns:
      type: Public
    masters: public
    nodes: public

---

apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-07-19T16:24:11Z
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: k8s.runningenv.cloud
  name: large_nodes
spec:
  image: kope.io/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13
  machineType: t3.xlarge
  maxSize: 2
  minSize: 2
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: large_nodes
  role: Node
  rootVolumeSize: 64
  subnets:
  - ca-central-1a
  - ca-central-1b

---

apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-05-14T16:15:13Z
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: k8s.runningenv.cloud
  name: master-ca-central-1a
spec:
  image: kope.io/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13
  machineType: c4.large
  maxSize: 1
  minSize: 1
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: master-ca-central-1a
  role: Master
  subnets:
  - ca-central-1a

---

apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-05-14T16:15:13Z
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: k8s.runningenv.cloud
  name: nodes
spec:
  image: kope.io/k8s-1.12-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2019-05-13
  machineType: t3.large
  maxSize: 5
  minSize: 5
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: nodes
  role: Node
  subnets:
  - ca-central-1a
  - ca-central-1b
```

**8. Please run the commands with most verbose logging by adding the `-v 10` flag.
  Paste the logs into this report, or in a gist and provide the gist link here.**
Logs from kube-controller-manager

```
I0723 17:05:09.115034       1 shared_informer.go:119] stop requested
E0723 17:05:09.115219       1 controller_utils.go:1030] Unable to sync caches for garbage collector controller
E0723 17:05:09.115373       1 garbagecollector.go:233] timed out waiting for dependency graph builder sync during GC sync (attempt 300)
E0723 17:05:09.130184       1 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/controller/garbagecollector/graph_builder.go:124: Failed to list <nil>: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"
E0723 17:05:09.144553       1 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/controller/garbagecollector/graph_builder.go:124: Failed to list <nil>: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"
I0723 17:05:09.416248       1 garbagecollector.go:204] syncing garbage collector with updated resources from discovery (attempt 301): added: [{Group:auth.kope.io Version:v1alpha1 Resource:users} {Group:config.auth.kope.io Version:v1alpha1 Resource:authconfigurations} {Group:config.auth.kope.io Version:v1alpha1 Resource:authproviders}], removed: []
I0723 17:05:09.618069       1 controller_utils.go:1027] Waiting for caches to sync for garbage collector controller
E0723 17:05:10.133851       1 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/controller/garbagecollector/graph_builder.go:124: Failed to list <nil>: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"
E0723 17:05:10.152706       1 reflector.go:125]
```

**9. Anything else do we need to know?**
Tried connecting to etcd and this was the response

```
root@ip-172-20-48-95:/tmp/etcd-download-test# ./etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2380 --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.crt --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-client.key  --ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/kube-apiserver/etcd-ca.crt --debug cluster-health
Cluster-Endpoints: https://127.0.0.1:2380
cURL Command: curl -X GET https://127.0.0.1:2380/v2/members
cluster may be unhealthy: failed to list members
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

error #0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

`kubectl get cs` response

```
I0723 13:16:52.688710   95389 request.go:947] Response Body: {"kind":"ComponentStatusList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/api/v1/componentstatuses"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"scheduler","selfLink":"/api/v1/componentstatuses/scheduler","creationTimestamp":null},"conditions":[{"type":"Healthy","status":"True","message":"ok"}]},{"metadata":{"name":"controller-manager","selfLink":"/api/v1/componentstatuses/controller-manager","creationTimestamp":null},"conditions":[{"type":"Healthy","status":"True","message":"ok"}]},{"metadata":{"name":"etcd-1","selfLink":"/api/v1/componentstatuses/etcd-1","creationTimestamp":null},"conditions":[{"type":"Healthy","status":"True","message":"{\"health\": \"true\"}"}]},{"metadata":{"name":"etcd-0","selfLink":"/api/v1/componentstatuses/etcd-0","creationTimestamp":null},"conditions":[{"type":"Healthy","status":"True","message":"{\"health\": \"true\"}"}]}]}
I0723 13:16:52.693112   95389 table_printer.go:43] Unable to decode server response into a Table. Falling back to hardcoded types: attempt to decode non-Table object into a v1beta1.Table
I0723 13:16:52.693491   95389 table_printer.go:43] Unable to decode server response into a Table. Falling back to hardcoded types: attempt to decode non-Table object into a v1beta1.Table
I0723 13:16:52.693534   95389 table_printer.go:43] Unable to decode server response into a Table. Falling back to hardcoded types: attempt to decode non-Table object into a v1beta1.Table
I0723 13:16:52.693556   95389 table_printer.go:43] Unable to decode server response into a Table. Falling back to hardcoded types: attempt to decode non-Table object into a v1beta1.Table
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health": "true"}
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the log there is something wrong with the Etcd certificate:

```
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: x509:
certificate signed by unknown authority

error #0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Please read the documentation how to create etcd certificates again and try to fix it.